I cant get my origin back on my armature automatically
I am trying to apply origin to geometry but it ends up being offset. I moved it back to the center of the armature manually but this created an undesirable result when trying to use the symmetrize function. Why can i not get the origin to get back to the center? Is it because it averages the locations of all bones when using origin to geometry? Do i need to recreate the armature from scratch in order to get the origin to be on the bottom middle bone?


Origin to Geometry doesn't set the Origin back to where it was previous to mvoing it. It sets it at the Center of the geometry, in your case the armature, but since it has bones for the limbs, wich stick out, said command gives you a, as you say, offset result.
A solution i'd use is to enter Edit Mode for the armature and select the Bottom Spine Bone (I think that's where you want the origin to be), now press SHIFT+S and select Cursor to Selected. Leave Edit Mode, right click> Set Origin> Origin to 3D Cursor. Et Voila, the Origin should now be exactly where you wanted it to be.
Hope it helps
